# rescueing from a timeout error on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rescue

I know that the long term solution is to try to prevent getting a timeout error. but every now and then on my applicaiton, I am getting a time out error. I have been trying to rescue from it and redirect to the homepage. instead of showing a 404, or a 500 error.

This is what my code looks like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  rescue_from Timeout::Error, :with => :rescue_from_timeout

  def rescue_from_timeout
    redirect_to users_root_path
  end
  ...
end
```

The problem is that I am still getting the Timeout Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally like to include all the code in the rescue_from block for readability:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  rescue_from Timeout::Error do |e|
    ## log e if needed
    return redirect_to users_root_path

  end

  ...
end
```

That should work as intended (I don't even know if the return is needed)

Comment: I am not sure the return is needed either but normally for redirection as a terminal event it would be `redirect_to user_root_path and return` if you wanted to stop the execution of any code after the redirection.